# 'Query was empty'-error

Tags: php, full-text-search

Here's my code I keep getting a "query empty error". I am trying to get the sql to query the database to return a answer using fulltext (newbie)

```
<?php
include ('db_connect.inc.php');
$questions = $_GET['string'];

$terms = explode(" ", $questions);
$string = "SELECT DISTINCT Answer, MATCH(Questions.Questions) AGAINST('";
$string2 = "AS relevance FROM Questions, Answers WHERE Questions.Answer_id =               Answers.Answer_ID AND MATCH(Questions.Questions) AGAINST('";

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($terms); $i++)
{
    if($i == sizeof($terms))
{
    $string = $string + $terms[$i] + "')";
    $string2 = $string2 + $terms[$i] + "') LIMIT 1";
}
else
{
    $string = $string + $terms[$i] + ",";
    $string2 = $string2 + $terms[$i] + ",";
}
}

$result = mysql_query($string . " " > $string2) or die(mysql_error());
echo $result;

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];
?>
```

Comment: Second thing, in PHP, concatenating strings is done with the `.` operator, not the `+` operator.

Answer (score 0):

In your line:

```
$result = mysql_query($string . " " > $string2) or die(mysql_error());
```

The expression `$string . " " > $string2` will evaluate to `true` or `false`, which, well, is not a string, let alone being a valid SQL query.

The reason is that `>` is a comparison operator that, in your case, compares two strings lexicographically. So if `$string . " "` is after `$string` in lexicographical order, your expression evaluates to `true`. Otherwise it evaluates to false `false`.